# Is union type available in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, union-types

Typed array like `$arrIntOnly = [Int[]]@(1, 2, 3)` is useful to ensure that all elements are valid type, but is it possible to define multiple types like `$arrIntOrString = [[Int | String][]]@(1, "two", 3)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell does *not* have a union data type, but you can use PowerShell's *default* arrays, which are `[object[]]`-typed and can therefore contain elements of *any type*:

```bash
# Note: @(...) around the array isn't strictly necessary.
$arrIntOrString = 1, 'two', 3
```

There's no direct way to *limit* what specific types are permitted.

However, you can use a *validation attribute* - of type [`System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) in this case - to enforce that the elements are limited to specified types:

```bash
[ValidateScript({ $_ -is [int] -or $_ -is [string] })] $arrIntOrString = 1, 'two', 3
```

The above would enforce the specified types both on initial assignment and later modifications; e.g., the following attempt to later "add"<sup>[1]</sup> an element of a non-permitted type would *fail*:

```bash
# FAILS, because $true (of type [bool]) is neither an [int] nor [string]
$arrIntOrString += $true
```

Unfortunately, the error message is somewhat obscure: `MetadataError: The variable cannot be validated because the value System.Object[] is not a valid value for the arrIntOrString variable.`

Note that this validation is fairly *slow*, given that a script block (`{ ... }`) must be executed *for each element*.

---

You can also apply this technique to *parameter declarations*, which in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* allows you to define a custom error message:

```bash
Function Foo {
  param(
    # Note: Use of ErrorMessage requires PS 7+
    [ValidateScript({ $_ -is [int] -or $_ -is [string] }, ErrorMessage = 'Please pass an integer or a string.')]
    $IntOrString
  )
  $IntOrString
}

Foo -IntOrString 1.0 # Fails validation
```

---

<sup>[1] Arrays are fixed-length data structures, so what PowerShell does when you "add" to an array with `+=` is to create a *new* array behind the scenes, with the new element(s) appended. Efficiently extensible alternatives to arrays are the non-generic [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) type (e.g., `[System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 'two', 3)`) and the generic [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) type (e.g., `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] (1, 'two', 3)`). Then use the `.Add()` method to add to these collections; note that the `ArrayList.Add()` method returns a value, which you can suppress with `$null = ...`. To initialize an *empty* collection of either type, cast `@()` to the type literal or call its static `::new()` method.</sup>

Comment: @theberzi, no, PowerShell doesn't have a union data type (I've updated the answer to make that clear), and this answer offers an _approximation_, in the context of _arrays_, which is what the question is about. However, you can apply the `ValidationScript` technique to parameter declarations as well - please see my update.